# Why can't mathematics prove that Tic-tac-toe is a simple game?

Tags: foundations-of-mathematics

Why can't mathematics prove that Tic-tac-toe is a simple game? Tell me if I am wrong, but we can prove that chess is less complex than tic-tac-toe, by counting the number of actions possible if we define what complexity is, but I don't think mathematics can prove it is a simple game, how do we do this? Do we have to define what simple is, and if so can we do so mathematically? Can you tell me what are the things that make it difficult or impossible to do so?

Comment: "We can prove that chess is less complex than chess"??? Did you mean "less complex than  tic-tac-toe"? And there is little point to defining "simple" when there is a pretty straightforward and [provably optimal strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy) in tic-tac-toe for both players, which, informally, means exactly that it is pretty simple (to the extent that this vague and context dependent predicate can be circumscribed).

Comment: It implies that it is more simple, but it doesn't "prove" it mathematically.

Comment: There is no "proving mathematically" anything expressed in loose language of this sort.

Comment: Please give references to where you got this from.

Comment: "chess is less complex than tic-tac-toe" I think you meant that the other way around... https://www.pipmodern.com/post/complexity-state-space-game-tree

Comment: You are making the assumption that mathematics can prove all things. This is a mistake. Math cannot prove all things. Math can prove you are a human being. Mathematicians would say you need to consult someone in science not math. Math is a topic area that has many subsets but it doesn't cover all we know or all reality. Your question already seems to imply that you know of at least one thing math cannot prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematicians have well-defined measures of *complexity* that they use to classify the difficulty level of different problems in the field. The most basic level of difficulty or simplicity measure is whether or not the problem as stated can be solved in a finite, a very large (but still finite), or an infinite number of steps.

In a game of tic-tac-toe, there are only a small number of possible moves at any step of the game and a small number of steps before the game is over, and so every possible sequence of moves in the game can be easily compiled in a list. Using that list you can then program a computer to play the game and never lose. In this sense the game of tic-tac-toe is a *solved problem*.

The Math stack exchange would probably be the right place to learn more about *complexity measures*.